# Magento create landing page with registration fields

Tags: magento, custom-controls, user-registration

I'm having e-commerce store built in magento. As by marketing point of view we planned to create a landing page which contains all registration fields and we'll run a separate adcampaign only for that to collect user's info.

I don't have any idea to do this.

Please give me a suggestion to make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but If you need to get users to login/register on your site right away when they visit, you could use this lovely extension.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12921/